# HTML social button issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

Im adding social buttons

[image]

to my site. but they are not centered on top of each other.

Tried to do `<center>` but doesn't do anything.

Herees my html code that im using

```
  <div id="footer">
    <a class="btn_social" href="https://discord.gg/DvXbGPdZ85"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
    <a class="btn_social" href="mailto:help@alphatron.games"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></a>
    <a class="btn_social" href="https://twitter.com/AlphatronGames"><i class="fa fa-laptop-code"></i></a>
    <a class="btn_social" href="https://www.instagram.com/alphatrongames/"><i class="fa fa-headset"></i></a>
    <br><br>
    <a class="btn_social" href="https://discord.gg/DvXbGPdZ85"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a>
    <a class="btn_social" href="mailto:help@alphatron.games"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></a>
    <a class="btn_social" href="https://twitter.com/AlphatronGames"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a class="btn_social" href="https://www.instagram.com/alphatrongames/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
  </div>
```

Heres the css code that Im using.

```
.btn_social {
    font-size:18px;
    color:#fff;
    margin:40px 20px;
    padding:15px 18px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:#000;
    transition:0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.btn_social:hover {
    color:#000;
    background:#fff;
    cursor:pointer;
}

@media (max-width: 900px){
    .btn_social {
        font-size:14px;
        margin:10px;
        padding:10px 11px;
    }
}
```

Not sure what to do or if its a problem with the icons but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your HTML & CSS?

Comment: The [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tag is an old deprecated tag used to align textual content. You will need to use CSS to center block elements like images.

Comment: You need to add code snippets till now what you have done in this way I can understand more easily. But for now, i can say you need to use  Flex box property of CSS display: flex, flex-direaction; column/row, flex-wrap: wrap, and then align-item:center and add justify-content:center;

Comment: I have posted an answer check it bro

Answer (score 1):

You can use a grid and center the elements by using `align-items`and `justify-content` to center all elements like in the snippet.

I'm not sure about my answer, your html don't include the images, so I replaced them by some text...

```css
    #footer{
            display:grid;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);/*adjust the size here*/
            grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 70px);/*adjust the size here*/ 
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: #000000;
        }
        #footer a{
            display: grid;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .btn_social {
            font-size:18px;
            color:#fff;
            margin:40px 20px;
            padding:15px 18px;
            border-radius:50%;
            background:#000;
            transition:0.4s ease-in-out;
        }
        .btn_social:hover {
            color:#000;
            background:#fff;
            cursor:pointer;
        }

        @media (max-width: 900px){
            .btn_social {
                font-size:14px;
                margin:10px;
                padding:10px 11px;
            }
        }
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div><a class="btn_social" href="https://discord.gg/DvXbGPdZ85"><i class="fas fa-home">link</i></a></div>
    
    <div><a class="btn_social" href="mailto:help@alphatron.games">icon<i class="fas fa-at"></i></a></div>
    
    <div><a class="btn_social" href="https://twitter.com/AlphatronGames">insta<i class="fa fa-laptop-code"></i></a></div>
    
    <div><a class="btn_social" href="https://www.instagram.com/alphatrongames/">logo<i class="fa fa-headset"></i></a></div>
    
    
    <div><a class="btn_social" href="https://discord.gg/DvXbGPdZ85">social<i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a></div>
    <div><a class="btn_social" href="mailto:help@alphatron.games"><i class="fas fa-at">tweet</i></a></div>
    <div><a class="btn_social" href="https://twitter.com/AlphatronGames"><i class="fab fa-twitter">mail</i></a></div>
    <div><a class="btn_social" href="https://www.instagram.com/alphatrongames/">media<i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the display flex property and center the elements by aligning items and justifying content. You can try the code snippet below.

if neccesary you can adjust the width and height of the footer as needed

```css
  #footer {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            gap: 2rem;
        }

        #footer a{
            color: rgb(102, 100, 100);
            margin-right: 1rem;
        }

        #footer a:hover{
            color: white;
        }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css"
            integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w=="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="footer">
            <div>
                <a class="btn_social" href="https://discord.gg/DvXbGPdZ85"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></a>
                <a class="btn_social" href="mailto:help@alphatron.games"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></a>
                <a class="btn_social" href="https://twitter.com/AlphatronGames"><i class="fa fa-laptop-code"></i></a>
                <a class="btn_social" href="https://www.instagram.com/alphatrongames/"><i class="fa fa-headset"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a class="btn_social" href="https://discord.gg/DvXbGPdZ85"><i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a>
                <a class="btn_social" href="mailto:help@alphatron.games"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></a>
                <a class="btn_social" href="https://twitter.com/AlphatronGames"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                <a class="btn_social" href="https://www.instagram.com/alphatrongames/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The image doesn't add anything to the answer as you can see the result directly in the code snippet...

Comment: Unfortunately, there are a lot of answers. To stand out from them, I placed the image as an intro. Please let me know how you can edit my post. How do you know that I am posting like this

Comment: Adding this kind of overhead will get just get you downvoted. Also see [privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: oh okey now i got it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to line them up from top to bottom and center it on the webpage.

Make the parent have the following CSS properties:

```
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The margin is set to '0 auto' making it in the center of its parent.

Answer (score -1):

Nav? or just Button?

using class=id"", and css argument each elements

Comment: An answer should not request any further information. Furthermore this "answer" is unclear